# Link a specific Group of Users, to an unbound form where the TeamLeaderID is posted through a txtBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have Users divided in Groups, however there are only two locations that the groups are further divided in... Post
I'm trying to display the Users from a Post when their TeamLeader Logon to the Form...

In a nutshell, TeamLeader Logon, goes to his personal Form and there he sees only the Users that he has to coach.

I'm getting to display the PostID and the TeamLeaderID just fine, however I think I screwed it up with the criteria for the PlayerID because it's returning blank.

This is an unbound Form btw.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim Post As String
Dim UserType As String
Dim User As String
Dim UserTypeID As Long
Dim PostID As Long
Dim TeamLeaderID As Long
Dim PlayerID As Long

    'Locate User Post and display it on the TeamLeaderF
    Post = DLookup("Post", "PostQ", "UserID = " & TempVars!TempUserID)
    Me.txtPost = Post
    
    'Locate User UserType and display it on the TeamLeaderF
    UserType = DLookup("UserType", "UserQ", "UserID = " & TempVars!TempUserID)
    Me.txtUserType = UserType
    
    'Locate PlayerName and display it on the TeamLeaderF
    User = DLookup("PlayerName", "UserQ", "UserID = " & TempVars!TempUserID)
    Me.txtWelcome = "Welcome " & User

    'Locate TeamLeaderID and display it on the TeamLeaderF    
    TeamLeaderID = DLookup("TeamLeaderID", "GroupQ", "UserID=" & TempVars!TempUserID)
    Me.txtTeamLeaderID = TeamLeaderID

    'Locate PostID and display it on the TeamLeaderF
    PostID = DLookup("PostID", "GroupQ", "UserID = " & TempVars!TempUserID)
    Me.txtPostID = PostID

    'Locate the PlayerID, by checking if the ID's in "txtPostID & txtTeamLeaderID" in the GroupQ are equal to the one they are assigned to
    PlayerID = DLookup("PlayerID", "GroupQ", "UserID=""& PostID & "" AND TeamLeaderID =" & TempVars!TempUserID)
    Me.txtPlayerID = PlayerID`
```

Comment: If UserID is number type, don't use quote or apostrophe delimiters. `& "" AND Me.txtTeamLeaderID ="` makes no sense. This should be a field in table, not a control on form. These DLookup expressions can be in textbox ControlSource.

Comment: @June7, The form is an unbound form, so there are just txtboxes that pull their values from these ControlSources. 
I was hoping to catch the expression that is posted on the form and use it to validate what players to display on the form.

Comment: Doesn't alter my comments. What do you mean by "players" - plural? Domain aggregate function can return only a single value. Also, if UserID = PostID, why do you need PostID when you already have UserID? Should that last DLookup use `"PostID=" & PostID`. I advise not to give variables same names as fields.

Comment: @June7 The "Player" refers to the TeamMembers, I'm trying to load all of the "Player" , from "GroupQ", where their "PostID" coinsides with the one from their respective "TeamLeader" "PostID" on this Form, so that the TeamLeader can place their remarks
I'm unsure if I'm being clear enough...

Comment: It is not clear. Nothing in code shown will load 'all' of anything. It merely pulls single values into textboxes. Aside from that, did you correct errors noted?

Comment: Solved the problem, 
I created a continuous form with the PlayerID, the PlayerID then displays all the ID's in that specific Post range and a Dlookup would the display the Names corresponding to the ID

Thanks for all the suggestions, it helped me look at the problem from a different angle